# Sorting objects in alphabetical order

Tags: java, sorting

For my assignment, I have to create both a method to sort integers and Strings stored in an object class. Keep in mind, I HAD TO USE CASTS. I wanted to use generics, but my teacher INSISTS on me using 1.4.2 (which don't have generics). I can sort time, and for the alphabetical sort, I used my method to sort time and added a compareTo. I played with it a bit, but when I output it, it gives me everything I inputted in the order I inputted it. Not in alphabetical.

Here's the class I created to store input:

```
public class showInfo 
{
    String name;
    String day; 
    int time;    
}
```

The following is the method to sort by name!

```
//method to sort and display info
public static void sortName(){          
    for(int i = 0; i < show.size() - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < show.size() - 1; j++){
            if(((showInfo)show.get(i)).name.compareTo(((showInfo)show.get(i+1)).name) > 0){
                showInfo temp = new showInfo();
                temp.name = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).name;
                temp.day = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).day;
                temp.time = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).time;

                ((showInfo)show.get(j)).time = ((showInfo)show.get(i)).time;
                ((showInfo)show.get(j)).day = ((showInfo)show.get(i)).day;
                ((showInfo)show.get(j)).name = ((showInfo)show.get(i)).name;

                ((showInfo)show.get(i)).time = temp.time;
                ((showInfo)show.get(i)).day = temp.day;
                ((showInfo)show.get(i)).name = temp.name;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance. :)

(PS. I'm aware I need to change "showInfo" to "ShowInfo", but I'll do it when I'm finished.)

Comment: *my teacher INSISTS on me using 1.4.2* -> Poor students.

Comment: YOu can look into this http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Comment: Is your teacher a time traveler from the past? Java 1.4.2? O_o

Comment: tell your teacher - " if you dont wanna get advanced let us be :P "

Answer (score 3):

One problem with your code is that you are comparing `show.get(i)` with `show.get(i+1)` but then swapping `show.get(i)` with `show.get(j)`. You should be comparing to `show.get(j)`. Also, the inner loop should go to `j < show.size()` rather than `show.size() - 1`. Finally, you can start the inner loop at `i + 1` instead of at `0`.

Once you determine that you need to swap, you can do much better by simply swapping references in the list, rather than swapping each field:

```
showInfo tmp = (showInfo)show.get(i);
show.set(i, show.get(j));
show.set(j, tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `show` is a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) and you have to sort by `name`.

First, make `showInfo` implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html):

```
public class showInfo implements Comparable
{
    String name;
    String day; 
    int time;

    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        showInfo other = (showInfo) o;
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    }  
}
```

Then, use [`Collections.sort()'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) on the list:

```
Collections.sort(show);
```

Comment: You could also write a Comparator if you can't modify showInfo

Comment: Since it sounds like the OP has to sort multiple different ways, wouldn't writing multiple `Comparator`s make more sense?

Comment: Being this is an assignment from their teacher, they almost certainly are required to implement the sorting logic themselves, rather than relying on `Collections.sort`.  Wondering whether implementing `Comparable` or writing `Comparator`s is more appropriate is kinda moot.

Comment: Being lazy, I will always take the easiest way to do something, unless specified otherwise (and in this case it wasn't).

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using `i` here :

```
if(((showInfo)show.get(i)).name.compareTo(((showInfo)show.get(i+1)).name) > 0){
```

I believe the second `i` should be `j` to achieve bubble sort

```
if(((showInfo)show.get(i)).name.compareTo(((showInfo)show.get(j+1)).name) > 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this....

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class myComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((o1.toString().charAt(0) > o2.toString().charAt(0)) ? 1 : (o1
                .toString().charAt(0) == o2.toString().charAt(0)) ? 0 : -1);
    }
}

public class Sample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add("hello");
        l.add("abc");
        l.add("World");
        l.add("hi");

        System.out.println("Before sorting");
        for (Object i : l) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }

        Collections.sort(l, new myComparator());

        System.out.println("After sorting");
        for (Object i : l) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you look for, it uses *casting* insteads of *generics*, anyway, i hope this will help

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6YNWSAXB)